# How to redirect user to url "/home" after some request is complete using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to redirect user to "/home" page after the load() request completes using react.

below is my code,

```
function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const {setIsLoading} = React.useContext(LoadingContext);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {//add  a callback to redirect user to "/home" page
                setIsLoading(false); 
            });
        }
    }
}

function Main ({user}: Props) {
    useAnother(user.id); 
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <React.suspense>
                <Switch>
                    <Route 
                        path="/" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <FirstComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Route 
                        path="/items" 
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <SecondComp {...routeProps} />
                        )}
                     />
                     //many other routes like these
                 </Switch>
            </React.suspense>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

Now within useAnother method after load() finishes i want to add a callback to load method to redirect user to "/home" page.

how can i do it. could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useHistory` Hook to Redirect the User.
The useHistory hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function useAnother(Id: string) {
    const [compId, setCompId] = React.useState(undefined);
    const {setIsLoading} = React.useContext(LoadingContext);
    const comp = useCurrentComp(Id);
    const load = useLoad();
    // Using useHistory Hook
    let history = useHistory();
    if (comp && comp.id !== compId) {
        setCompId(comp.id);
        const prevCompId = compId !== undefined;
        if (prevCompId) {
            setIsLoading(true);
            load().then(() => {//add  a callback to redirect user to "/home" page
                setIsLoading(false); 
                history.push("/home");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control history API by manually creating it in `history.js`:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

Then you can load history to your component and use it in `useAnother` function. Bear in mind that you need to wrap `Switch` component to `Router` component passing the history as a prop.

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        // routes
    </Switch/>
</Router>
```

This answer gives the same result as using the `useHistory` hook, however gives more control when you test the component since it avoids to mock `react-router-dom` and implements `dependency injection`